# linking facebook share api to a button image

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

i don't want to use the default fb share button so I've created a button that symbolizes fb with nice hover, now i want to link it to the fb share api.is it possible to do that?

Comment: facebook api for sharing website on facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the javascript sdk and the feed dialog. Just assign your image an onclick event and then call the dialog function.  Below is the snippet from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
 <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
<p id='msg'></p>

<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```